# C++ Function Pointer as Default Template Argument

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, default, function-pointers

how do I write a function pointer as default template argument, I'am guessing to write it like this:

```
template<typename R,
         typename A,
         typename F=R (*PF)(A)> 
class FunctionPtr { ...
```

my question is,

1.is it possible?

2.if it is and my guess code above is correct, what the purpose of `PF` here? do I need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No, you don't need PF.

   ```
   template<typename R,
            typename A,
            typename F=R (*)(A)>
   ```

Comment: more question, how do i write for member function, like this? `template<typename C,typename R,typename A, typename F=R (C::*)(A)>`

Comment: got err. C2653 on VC'03 : " 'C' is not a class or namespace " on `typename F=R (C::*)(A)>`

Comment: I'am asked another question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450246/c-pointer-to-member-function-as-template-default-argument

Comment: @uray: How do you instantiate this? `C` has to be a class-type.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it is possible
2. The `PF` not only is useless but must be removed in this context. It would, for example, be necessary in the context of a function pointer declaration :

   ```
   int (*PF)(double) = &A::foo; // declares a 'PF' variable of type 'int (*)(double)'
   ```

   but it is neither required nor legal here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `typedef`ing pointer to function. `typedef R (*PF)(A);` then give `PF` as a default template argument.