# C++ Pointer to Member Function as Template Default Argument

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, function-pointers

is it possible, like this:

```
template< typename C,
          typename R,
          typename A,
          typename F=R (C::*)(A) >
class MemberFuncPtr { ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,it seems pretty right to me, I do not get any errors for this piece of code:

```
template< typename C, 
          typename R, 
          typename A, 
          typename F=R (C::*)(A) > 
class MemberFuncPtr
{
        C & Cmember;
        F f;
public:
        MemberFuncPtr(C & c, F func):Cmember(c), f(func) {}
        R DoIt(A & a)
        {
                return (Cmember.*f)(a);
        }
};
class classA
{
public:
        int toInt(double aa)
        {
                return int(aa);
        }
};
int main()
{
        classA aInstance;
        MemberFuncPtr<classA,int,double> xx(aInstance,&classA::toInt); 
        return 0;
}
```

You can observe the code [here](http://www.ideone.com/aKYcw).

Comment: Actually, in C++ main() must return integer, so your code is not exactly valid with standard. Moreover, argument of `MemberFuncPtr::DoIt` must be lvalue, which could be little pain. My little enhanced version: http://ideone.com/gA7kJ

Comment: @Pawel Zubrycki: Yes, I forgot about the main() but your version is enhanced with what, 3 lines of obvious, non-magical code? Come on....

Comment: That is why I called it little.

Comment: @Pawel Zubrycki: So does your little enhanced version have anything to do with your statement that `MemberFuncPtr::DoIt` must be lvalue?

Comment: Nope, unless you'll remove reference it's rather impossible to do it in C++03.

Comment: @Pawel Zubrycki: `main` is special and doesn't need an explicit `return` statement. 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] / 6: If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is of executing `return 0;`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Thanks for the clarification. probably I should start to read the standarts immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is perfectly valid.

```
class X {
public:
    void Y() {
    }
};

int main() {
    MemberFuncPtr<X, void, void> func;
}
```

Build succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Using `typedef` will make your code more user-friendly. Just `typedef` pointer to function, then use it as other types.

Comment: I thought, typedef is not possible for declaring template arguments

Comment: how do I write typedef for templated types ? (ok sad_man already replied it, its not possible)

Comment: typedef R(C::func*)(A); then use func as template argument.

Comment: Execuse me, I was wrong. I hadn't seen that C is also comes as template argument.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can write template wrapper:

```
template < typename C >
class CWrapper
{
 typedef R(C::func*)(A);
 C* realC;
 Cwrapper(C* c):realC(c){}
};
```

then write you class this way:

```
template < typename C,
           typename R,
           typename F = C::func >
class MemberFuncPtr{...
```

then make `MemberFuncPtr< CWrapper <C>, R> memFuncPtr;`

Comment: Not gonna compile - `CWrapper` don't know anything about `R` and `A`

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Sad_man's code with some C++0x magic: http://ideone.com/rng6V (probably not gonna work for you, as not many compilers has C++0x :-|)

Works with rvalues and there is example how to achieve what you want with lambda functions.

Comment: Seems whole ideone.com is currently down.